# SELECT name WHERE point in square

Tags: mysql, sql, math, geometry

I know that this is more of a Math problem, but I am not certaint as to how to perform math correctly in a query anyways. What Im trying to do, is get a column from a database, where a point (x, y) is inside a region saved in another column of that row (x, y) - (x + 16, y + 16).

The database loks something like:

```
+--------+---------------+
|  Name  |    Position   |
+--------+---------------+
|Area1   |16:32          |
|Area2   |-32:16         |
|Area3   |128:64         |
+--------+---------------+
```

An area is the saved cordinates (X:Y) + 16. It's basically a grid of 16x16 areas.
I'm trying to get the name of the area by the position of a point (x, y), which can be anywhere in that area.

If this would make things easier, It is possible to change the "Position" column to 2 diffent one aka something like:

```
+--------+---------------+---------------+
|  Name  |  Position_x   |  Position_Y   |
+--------+---------------+---------------+
|Area1   |16             |32             |
|Area2   |-32            |16             |
+--------+---------------+---------------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `math correctly in a query anyways` database is not a calculator. in most cases should do your math first, then use results in your query

Comment: The issue is, i cannot do the math in PHP, without pulling the whole table, and that table could get quite big... That's why I'm trying to do all the math on the SQL server, to send as less data as possible between the SQL and PHP servers

Comment: What SQL dialect and version?

Comment: @Sparky MySQL 5.7.29-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to check that the `x` value is between `Position_x` and `Position_x+15` (inclusive) and the same for `y`:

```
SELECT *
FROM areas
WHERE 20 BETWEEN Position_x AND Position_x + 15
  AND 40 BETWEEN Position_y AND Position_y + 15
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Name    Position_x  Position_Y
Area1   16          32
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ia24gWcBokjKxo3rAGEpC9/0)

Comment: I think that, that will work! One question though: Is it possible to do the same, if the table looked like my first example?

Comment: @kriskotooBG it would be possible, but a pain... data should never really be stored as a delimited list in a table as it makes it hard to write queries against. Anyway see this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ia24gWcBokjKxo3rAGEpC9/2